# What has quantum entanglement to do with navigating on the magnetic field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

In this video is simply explained how robins use the magnetic field to navigate. But the author is talking about quatum entangelment, but I don't see how this is related to navigating. Now there are some electrons in the birds eye entangled but what does this add to the capacity of navigation?

min. 8:10
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUlX2rODSQI

Comment: Someone might come up with a more complete answer about knowledge in the area, but at this time biological mechanisms involving quantum effects are mostly just proposals by a couple scientists who write a lot of books and, apparently, YouTube videos. Some of these quantum effects are about biochemical reactions, and are probably legit but only interesting in the chemistry (i.e., it might tell you *why* a certain reaction occurs with a very high efficiency, but you don't really need to know that "why" to understand the biology) - in other contexts, like this one, it's mostly speculative.

Comment: The speculation seems to be that quantum entanglement is important for state stability within the molecules that are sensing the magnetic field.